Can we to get the convergence in probability in this situation?
I was studying the various types of convergence and I met a question for convergence in probability. I have known that for probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$, if $X_n(\omega)\to X(\omega)$ $\mathbb{P}$-a.s., then one has $X_n(\omega)\to X(\omega)$ in probability.

My question is if for any $\omega\in\Omega$, there exists $n_k(\omega)$ ($n_k$ may depend on $\omega$), such that $X_{n_k(\omega)}(\omega)\to X(\omega)$ (convergence in pointwise), can we find subsequences of $n$, denote it by $\widetilde{n}$, such that $X_{\widetilde{n}}(\omega)\to X(\omega)$ in probability?

I think may be we need a generalization of Egoroff's theorem to find $\widetilde{n}$, such that $X_{\widetilde{n}}(\omega)\to X(\omega)$ uniformly on some set A with $\mathbb{P}(A)<\epsilon$. But I don't know how to do it. Thanks!

No. Consider $\Omega=[0, 1]$ with the usual Lebesgue measure. Let $X_{2n}=\mathcal{X}_{[0,\ 1/2]}$ and $X_{2n+1}=\mathcal{X}_{(1/2,\ 1]}$ for $n\geq 1$, and $X=1$. Then $\mu(\omega\in [0, 1] : |X(\omega)-X_n(\omega)|=1)=1/2$ so there cannot be convergence in probability along a subsequence.
